# Google API Shortner Issues

Tags: api, url-shortener

I'm using the above API to shorten a batch of URLs during a cron job.

My quota is set in my dashboard as: 1000,000 per day and 100/sec/user

My PHP script uses the sleep function set to 1 in an attempt to prevent my limit per second from exceeding:

```
     sleep(1);
     $this->getShortUrl($url);
```

When I watch the graph in my dashboard all works ok until I get to around 314 requests which were made in appox an 8 minute period. After this I receive a host of 403 errors and according to the graph my per second average seems to increase to 1.5 / second.

I'm not sure how this is possible with the sleep which should prevent ever any more than 1 request per second. There are no other processes making requests with my account or key and the pattern is repeated daily.

Does anyone know if a someone clicks to Expand a URL, does this also count as an API call and if so could this be causing the issue?